# Слово "зачикировать"

Tags: этимология, значение-слов

Из фильма "Девчата":

— То ли еще будет.
— Да, здорово мы ее ***зачикировали***, только знаешь, Илюша, долго мы так не протянем.

Что за слово такое *"зачикировать"?*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Не знаю контекста (возможно, употреблено в значении "повязать", "захомутать", "зацепить" и т. п.), но несов. вид такого глагола есть в "[Словаре русских
говоров центральных районов Красноярского края](http://www.kspu.ru/upload/documents/2011/10/10/755fbc88e15d007acfe69fc2159aa7e0/slovar-rus-govorov-krasnoyar-kraya5-tpdf.pdf)" (с.113):

> ЧИКИРОВАТЬ, несов., перех.; спец. Связывать спиленные деревья тросом
> для транспортировки. — В тайге бригада трактористов чикирует лес и
> увозит на плодбище. Дв.: Слиз. СЮГ, ; ССГ, .
>
> ЧИКИРА, -ы, ж.; спец. Трос, с помощью которого крепятся брёвна для
> транспортировки. Ср.: ЧЕКИР. — Трос есть такой — чикира, им брёвна
> цепляют. Дв.: Слиз. СЮГ, ; ССГ, .

Исходное значение слова подтверждается сюжетом: фильм имеет отношение к "**леспромхозу**".

Comment: Спасибо большое, Александр! Да, наверно, тут ближе всего значение "захомутать". А контекст сейчас скажу какой. На танцах Тося отказала Илье станцевать, и тот отомстил: в столовой со своими приятелями сказали, сговорившись, что щи невозможно есть, с лягушками они, что ли. Потом показывают, как Тося (она готовила) расстроилась, а потом этот диалог, как они радовались своей "победе".

Comment: По всем критерия - убедительно. Кроме одного момента. В инете слово встречается в текстах, ну совершенно далеких от всякого леса ("тут меня менты и зачикировали", "сломанный ноготь зачикировали" - и проч.). Вот как оно туда-то попало? Можно, конечно, предположить, что из фильбма и пошло, но уж очень натянуто.

Comment: @behemothus: тоже не думаю, что из фильма пошло. Просто, видимо, на Урале это слово употребляли по отношению и к лесу, и в переносном смысле, а переносные значения, получается, были самые разные: от того, что в фильме, до ногтя. Хотя про ноготь не очень понятно... Как вы предложили, зафиксировали, что ли?

Comment: Ноготь "чик-чик" (по наитию употребили знакомое из фильма - выражение включают в сетевые списки известных реплик актера http://krymology.info/index.php/%D0%A4%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%BF%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B2,_%D0%A0%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%B0%D0%BD_%D0%A1%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B3%D0%B5%D0%B5%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%87 ), да отстригли. А с ментами могло быть и сознательно, по значению "повязали".

Comment: Точно, остригли!

Comment: Ноготь по контексту там именно починили. Пишет женщина, которая мейк-ап попортила перед выходом в свет, но каким-то там хитрым способом ей его восстановили.  Впрочем, это не актуально. Я, как написал под другом ответом, посмотрел этот эпизод. Весь контекст (точнее будет сказать в данном случае - "весь аньтураж"), коворит о том, что Alex_ander прав.

Answer (score 2):

Контекст бы посмотреть. Фильм наизусть не помню, а фраза, хоть и является, по мнению Вики, крылатой, не на слуху.

Но вообще-то слово встречается. В разных контекстах и смыслах - починили, связали, утрамбовали, исправили, арестовали... Включая и переносные значения слов этого ряда. Общее значение я бы определил как "зафиксировали".

Про этимологию ничего сказать не могу. Подозреваю, правда, что связано с междометием "чик" (чик - и нету!), но нечем подтвердить.

Comment: Спасибо большое! Долго соображал, о какой Вике речь.))))